# JavaFX - Centering button in specific GridPane nodes

Tags: javafx

I would like to center specifically one button in my GrisPane. It seems to be something missing in its declaration.

Below is my present output with the associated code.

```
public class Beta extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        final int numCols = 6 ;
        final int numRows = 12 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            colConst.setPercentWidth(100.0 / numCols);
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            rowConst.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);         
        }
                
        Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
        okBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        root.add(okBtn, 3, 9, 1, 1);    
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

> ```java
> Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
> okBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
> ```

Is setting the [alignment property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) of the `Button`. That property:

> Specifies how the text and graphic within the Labeled should be aligned when there is empty space within the Labeled.

<sup>**Note:** A `Button` is a `Labeled` (i.e., it's a subtype).</sup>

You want to set `GridPane`'s alignment constraints for the `Button`. You can set constraints for individual child nodes. If I understand your goal correctly, you likely want:

```java
Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
// these are static methods of GridPane
GridPane.setHalignment(okBtn, HPos.CENTER);
GridPane.setValignment(okBtn, VPos.CENTER);
```

However, if you want every cell in a row/column to have the same alignment, then set the `valignment` and `halignment` properties of the appropriate `RowConstraints` and `ColumnConstraints`, respectively.